# Pine Script Error: The function 'sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency

Tags: pine-script

I keep getting this error -

The function 'sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.

Here is the pine script I'm using -

```html
//@version=4
study(title="niceCROSS (Ichimoku Base Line & SMMA)", shorttitle="niceCROSS", overlay=true)

basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods")

donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

plot(baseLine, color=color.purple, title="Base Line")

len = input(5, minval=1, title="SMMA Length")

src1 = input(close, title="Source")

smma = 0.0

smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src1, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src1) / len

plot(smma, color=color.lime, title="SMMA")
```

Please help me rewrite if possible. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, it's a warning, so it doesn't preven you from running the script. In this particular code, the `sma()` function is only called once, on the very first bar of the chart, so the calculation consistency of the SMA doesn't matter and the warning can be ignored. But if you want to get rid of the error, you can move the SMA to global scope like this:

```
<...>
sma = sma(src1, len)
smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src1) / len
plot(smma, color=color.lime, title="SMMA")
```